# Maven Nexus Issue - Authorization failed for 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, nexus, gitlab-ci-runner

We have been on this issue for days now.

Created a Gitlab CI Pipeline for a Java App that reads dependencies from Maven and Nexus

The gitlab pipeline was configured to run as a nexus user with admin rights, this has been verified many times.

But, when the gitlab pipeline is executed we get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hello-component: Could not resolve dependencies for project x.y.z:hello-component:jar:1.6-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at a.b:c:jar:4.5.1132100: Failed to read artifact descriptor for b:c:jar:4.5.1132100: Could not transfer artifact a.b:c:pom:4.5.1132100 from/to maven-snapshots (http://host:8081/repository/maven-snapshots): Authorization failed for http://host:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/a/b/c/4.5.1132100/nidp-4.5.1132100.pom 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project hello-component: Could not resolve dependencies for project x.y.z:hello-component:jar:1.6-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at a.b:c:jar:4.5.1132100
```

I have also used the following guide:

```
https://blog.sonatype.com/how-to-use-gitlab-ci-with-nexus
```

My POM has the below, with env variables configured in ci/cd/settings/variables:

```
     <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>maven-snapshots</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>http://host:8081/repository/maven-snapshots</nexusUrl>
                        <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://host:8081/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
            <url>http://host:8081/repository/maven-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <!--repository>
            <id>nexus.local</id>
            <url>$HOME/.m2/repository</url>
        </repository-->
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://host:8081/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
            <url>http://host:8081/repository/maven-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

The Gitlab CI runner has the following:

```
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/conf/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=/home/gitlab-runner/.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - /home/gitlab-runner/.m2/repository/
    - target/

stages:
  - build

CodeBuild:
  stage: build
  script:
   - /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -X clean package
  artifacts:
    name: “x—y-component"
    paths:
      - ./target/x—y-component.jar
```

Setting.xml on gitlab ci server has the following nexus user reference:

maven-snapshots
      [adminuser]
      [adminpassword]

Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure if help is still needed but it seems that You did not grant necessary privileges to role of the user which You use for deployment/resolving dependencies. Please grant role nx-repository-view-*-*-* privilege. Test it and then you can decrease scope depend on your needs.

Comment: Hell Pawel, I have updated with the root cause of the issue and how I fixed it at the time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue at the time was with corporate proxy blocking download from maven central etc

Edit the proxies section in your maven settings.xml, which could be located in your ~/.m2/settings.xml file.
Settings.xml also exists in your MAVEN_HOME, so ensure you are updating the correct settings.xml

```
<settings>
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>httpproxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>your-proxy-host</host>
        <port>your-proxy-port</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>add.host.that.needs.to.bypass.proxy.here|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
<proxy>
        <id>httpsproxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <host>your-proxy-host</host>
        <port>your-proxy-port</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>add.host.that.needs.to.bypass.proxy.here|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

</proxies>
</settings>
```